# Can't get the uids that back from post of fb:request-form on MVC

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, post, fbrequest-form

I'm tring to get the uids that user selected at the  but always back null the ids.

```
 <fb:request-form action="http://myapp/controller/index?id=<apid>&sk=<secret>"
        method="POST" invite="false" type="Invite" content="<fb:req-choice url='http://myapp/controller/index?id=<apid>&sk=<secret>' label='invite' />">
    <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" bypass="cancel"  cols=3  actiontext="Invite example"/>
    </fb:request-form>
```

After user invite, redirect to my action.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(long[] ids)
    {
        return null;

    }
```

the ids always return null.

Answer (score 0):

why on gods green earth are you transmiting your secret key in the form action ?

And to answer your question, you have to set invite="true" to get the ID's AFAIR. But be warned, the whole process has changed, and is using requests 2.0 but with very strict limitations. see http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17113 for details.

EDIT: fixed wrong bug id

Comment: Tks Rufinus. About the secret key, my fault rsrs.

Unfortunately I set invite="true" and nothing changed. the Ids parameter continue NULL. 

     <fb:request-form  method="POST" invite="true" action="[link](http://myapp/controller/index)"
                    type="Application Name" content="<fb:req-choice url='[link](http://myapp/controller/index)' label='@Model.Name invited you' />" > 
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use this application." />
                </fb:request-form>

Anything that I could be missing?

Comment: see http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17113#c19 for a "working" version. 
But maybe try this approch with the new requests 2.0 widget. seems to be the way todo it in the future http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/